# Qt Plugins: :-1: error: cannot find -lpnp_basictools

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I have been trying for days now to use third party libraries in my simple Qt projects, but to no success so far.

I have tried the [Plug & Paint Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-app-example.html) and the [Plug & Paint Basic Tools Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-plugins-basictools-example.html). The *tools/plugandpaint/plugins/basictools/basictools.pro* compiles OK, but the *tools/plugandpaint/app/app.pro* fails to compile:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lpnp_basictools
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have practically copy-pasted the sources from the website to my computer. What could I be missing.

**Windows 10**

**Qt Creator 3.6.0**

> *Based on Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)
>
>   Built on Dec 15 2015 01:01:38
>
>   From revision b52c2f91f5*

```
LIBS += your_lib_path/your_lib linux：LIBS += -L your_lib_path -lyour_lib win32：LIBS += your_lib_path/your_lib LIBS += -L lib/pcsc/ -lpcsclite LIBS += lib/pcsc/libpcsclite.a 2.add headers INCLUDEPATH += your_include_path INCLUDEPATH += . /usr/local/include）
```

[app.pro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-app-example.html)

```
TARGET = plugandpaint
DESTDIR = ..

QT += widgets

HEADERS        = interfaces.h \
                 mainwindow.h \
                 paintarea.h \
                 plugindialog.h
SOURCES        = main.cpp \
                 mainwindow.cpp \
                 paintarea.cpp \
                 plugindialog.cpp

LIBS           = -L../plugins -lpnp_basictools

if(!debug_and_release|build_pass):CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
   mac:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)_debug
   win32:LIBS = $$member(LIBS, 0) $$member(LIBS, 1)d
}

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/widgets/tools/plugandpaint
INSTALLS += target

CONFIG += install_ok  # Do not cargo-cult this!
```

[basictoolsplugin.pro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-plugins-basictools-example.html)

```
TEMPLATE      = lib
CONFIG       += plugin static
QT           += widgets
INCLUDEPATH  += ../../app
HEADERS       = basictoolsplugin.h
SOURCES       = basictoolsplugin.cpp
TARGET        = $$qtLibraryTarget(pnp_basictools)
DESTDIR       = ../../plugins

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/widgets/tools/plugandpaint/plugins
INSTALLS += target

CONFIG += install_ok  # Do not cargo-cult this!
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Plug & Paint (P&P)** example depends on the library generated from the **P&P Basic Tools (P&P-BT)** example. In other words, to run the first you need to compile and link the second. The **P&P** example is not standalone.

I think that you have two options to run **P&P**:

1. Compile **P&P-BT** and make sure that it's
   linked in **P&P**
2. If you are only interested in the
   dynamic plugins of the example, in **P&P** comment the lines that import the
   static library from the **P&P-BT** example.

I tested it and you have to comment some lines in the .pro file and 1 line in the main.cpp file.

Below I show a diff with the lines I changed and it compiles **P&P** without errors.

[image: diff showing changes in code to remove usage of static library]

When opened, it doesn't find any plugins because it isn't loading the default static library and because the hardcoded path of the dynamic libraries is empty. To test the dynamic plugins, change the path to the correct folder and compile again, or move the plugins to the hardcoded folder.

[image: plug and paint without any plugins]